# Using .NET Core packages on legacy .NET platforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, nuget, asp.net-core

I'm creating a NuGet package using one of those new "Class Library (Package)" templates in VS. I want to know, is there any way I can use my package from a PCL that does **not** use .NET Core?

For example, I have a package, `Enu`, with the following `project.json`:

```
{
    "title": "Enu",
    // project details...

    "dependencies": {
        "System.Runtime": "4.0.0"
    },

    "frameworks": {
        "dotnet": { }
    }
}
```

Then I have a legacy PCL that targets .NET 4.5, Windows 8, and Windows 8.1. When I try to install the package via `Install-Package Enu`, I get the following error:

```
PM> Install-Package Enu
# blah blah blah
Install-Package : Could not install package 'Enu 4.0.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile111', but the package does not contain 
any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
```

What can I do to fix this?

**note:** Weirdly enough, it works on a console application.

Comment: What frameworks are you targeting in the console app?

Comment: @DaveZych The console app is running on .NET 4.5.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question. I'm not positive, but I don't believe you can reference your .NET core app in anything but .NET Core.

Comment: @DaveZych I thought that too, but for some reason it still runs on the console even though the console uses the .NET Framework (and not .NET Core).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep, it's possible. Here's a nice graph for reference (taken from [here](http://oren.codes/2015/06/09/pcls-net-core-dnx-and-uwp/)):

[image]

**tl;dr** To target everything add this to your `project.json`:

```
"frameworks": {
    "dotnet": { }, // .NET 4.6 and DNX
    "net45": { }, // .NET Framework 4.5
    "netcore45": { } // WinRT and Silverlight
}
```

Comment: Note that DNX is abandonned and replaced by .NET Core CLI. So instead of DNXCORE50, it is now NETSTANDARD1.5 for Class Libraries, and NETCOREAPP1.0 for applications such as test projects.