# 'number' is not a valid type for an input tag - On my local machine only

Tags: asp.net, html, iis, webforms

I am trying to work on an already live Asp.Net/Web Forms project.

It all compiles fine in visual studio but when I run a particular page under my local IIS I get

> 'number' is not a valid type for an input tag.

on this line of html:

```
<input type="number" ID="txtNum" runat="server" class="txt" step='0.01'
   value='0.00' placeholder='0.00' min="0" />
```

There are a lot of people complaining of the same problem but the only solutions I am seeing is to update the code or HTML which is something I can't do as this works on the live server and on another developers machine.

**UPDATE** (based on suggested duplicate)

I have already looked at this question:

[How can I use HTML5 email input type with server-side .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232079/how-can-i-use-html5-email-input-type-with-server-side-net)

It suggests installing an update to .net 4
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2468871.
I think this machine was installed after 2011 anyway but either way the updates wont install it says:

> KB2468871v2 does not apply, or is blocked by another condition on your computer.

I dont know if this means the updates already installed or not??

The other answers suggest code/html changes which I am unable to do as this is already working elsewhere.

**What am I missing on my machine?**

Comment: Can you check if your browser supports HTML 5 ?

Comment: What you want to render is `HtmlGenericControl`. Check if current IIS & browser version supports HTML 5 input types.

Comment: You might want to check the localization settings and the decimal separator for that localization.

Comment: @AbhishekMaurya I'm using Chrome, so definitely supports HTML 5

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto How do I check if IIS supports HTML 5?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use HTML5 email input type with server-side .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232079/how-can-i-use-html5-email-input-type-with-server-side-net)

Comment: Update your .NET Framework installation, this has been fixed in 2011 already.

Comment: @CodeCaster I have updated the question regarding the possible duplicate post as I had already come across it.

Comment: Probably you mean WebForms?

Comment: Did you try to run `aspnet_regiis.exe -i`? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h(VS.80).aspx

Comment: @Bex You will have to upgrade framework version to .net 4.0 or above because type="number" support is provided by .net framework version 4.0 onwards

Comment: Regarding the KB2468871 installation problem, you can try [the solution posted by scsmith2](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/01487b43-9dff-4dfd-8415-ab54f6cdc12a/update-for-microsoft-net-framework-4-kb2468871-failes-continously?forum=netfxsetup). He had to go to the Control Panel and repair the "Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Client Profile", and then he could install the patch successfully.

Comment: @ConnorsFan I do not have MS .NET Framework 4 Client profile.. the lowest version of .net I have is 4.5 installed and I cannot install 4 as it says already higher version installed

Comment: Personally, I suggest to use jQuery inputMask.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This makes no sense.. but as inspired by this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27561096/390501

I updated my Target Framework in Visual Studio to 4.5.1 rather than 4.5 and now the page loads without a parser error!

Answer (score 3):

Use this code to use HTML5 input type:

Use this in .aspx file:

```
<input type="text" placeholder='0.00' ID="txtNum" runat="server" class="txt/>
```

Use this in .cs file:

```
 txtNum.Attributes["type"] = "number";
 txtNum.Attributes["value"] = "0.00";
 txtNum.Attributes["min"] = "0";
 txtNum.Attributes["step"] = "0.01";
```

Comment: As I said in the question I cannot update the code or html as this works fine for everyone else.

Answer (score 1):

The mainly  problem is **compatibility issue**  while  you using `runat="server"` on input field.  If you are using dot.net framework below than 4, then you could be getting this problem.

### Solution:

Remove `runat="server"` and call the textbox in server side by using `Request.Form("name")`. Please do, be the text box as html input instead of using `runat="server"`

**[Update for the .NET Framework 4: March, 2011](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2468871/update-for-the--net-framework-4-march--2011) -** 
[image]

and please visit this discussions

[Render ASP.NET TextBox as HTML5 Input type "Number"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9398356/render-asp-net-textbox-as-html5-input-type-number)

### Details:

**Using HTML5 input types in ASP.NET Web Forms**

Now comes the main point - How to use the new input types in ASP.NET? Obviously, you can use raw  tags as shown above in your web form and then use `Request.Form` collection to access individual values but if you are developing a web forms based application chances are that you will be using server side controls (either HTML server controls or Web server controls) rather than raw HTML markup. In such cases your textboxes will take either of the following form:

```
<input id="Text1" type="text" runat="server" />
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Now the problem is that VS2010 default installation doesn't take into account the new input types provided by HTML5. As a result you can't use the new input types in your web forms. Luckily, there is an update available on  [MSDN Download Center](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=3556) that fixes the issue for Web server controls (but not for HTML server controls). If you have this update installed, you can use TextBox server control like this:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" type="date"></asp:TextBox>
```

Notice the type attribute added to `<asp:TextBox>` tag. This way you can specify any new HTML5 input type and the resultant control will be rendered accordingly. The way you access TextBox server control on the server remains unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your browser supports HTML5 or not.
If it supports and still not showing then explicitly tell the browser that you are using html5 tags.

Use this in your .aspx file.

`<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">`

Answer (score 0):

This issue happening because .net framework installed in your machine does not have ***System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputGenericControl*** class.

This class defines the methods, properties, and events for server-side access to the HTML5 input element. (Reference - MSDN)

It is available since .Net 4.5.

Steps to solve the problem

**1. make sure .Net 4.5 framework is available in the server machine.**

**2. make sure the target framework for the projects in your solution are pointing to .Net 4.5**

**3. Make sure the website is using 4.0 app pool in IIS.**

Comment: 4.5 installed, app pool pointing at 4.0 and target of VS is 4.5
This appears to be an IIS prob not VS as VS not complaining at all - only IIS when I run the site.

Answer (score 0):

**Check prerequisites for this update**
- To apply this update, you must have the .NET Framework 4 or the .NET Framework 4 Client Profile installed.
- To install this update, you must have Windows Installer 3.1 or a later version installed. To obtain the latest version of Windows Installer, visit the following Microsoft [website](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8483)

**if your machine already have the prerequisites**
- Running a visual studio product repair from the Programs and features, located on windows control panel.
- Rerun the patch, hotfix.

Comment: Cannot run the hot fix as it's not applicable. Apparently because I already have a higher version of .net installed. I donot have .net 4 or .net 4 client profile installed as I have .net 4.5 - 4.7 and it will not allow installation of a lower version.
Repairing VS made no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Installing [HTML 5 Updates for .NET 4](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/scothu/2011/08/10/html-5-updates-for-net-4/) from [Reliability Update 1 for the .NET](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2533523/reliability-update-1-for-the--net-framework-4)  should enable .net framework to understand html5 controls.

**Quoting msdn;**

> The first update was shipped with VS 2010 SP1. You can read about the
>   framework update here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2468871. One of
>   the features of HTML 5 is there are now new input types such as date,
>   url, email and more. While most browsers today don’t support these new
>   input types you should still use them today because most mobile
>   devices do support them and it changes the keyboard these devices
>   display. For example specifying `type=”email”` will cause many phones to
>   provide the `“@”` character on the keyboard. `type=”email”` or `type=”url”`
>   will cause many phones to provide the `“.com”` button on the keyboard as
>   a shortcut.
>
> Before the update above it was illegal to use these input types in Web
>   Forms. The following would generate an error:
>
> `<asp:TextBox id=”TextBoxEmail” runat=”server” type=”email” />`
>
> Because we were validating what values could be provided for the `type=
>    attribute.` **This validation was relaxed as part of the above update.**

Comment: Again I already have a higher version of .net installed so this update is not valid

Comment: Which .net framework version do you have installed? Is it not working on higher version? On which IIS version are you trying?

Comment: I have .net 4.7 and IIS 7 (running windows 7)

Comment: You may have a workaround by running the legacy app into .net 4.5 fx refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32772197/using-net-core-packages-on-legacy-net-platforms and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9398356/render-asp-net-textbox-as-html5-input-type-number

Answer (score 0):

> In vb.net

In `.aspx` page :

```
<input id="txtNum" runat="server"/>
```

In `.vb` page, in `PageLoad()`:

```
txtNum.Attributes.Add("type","number")
```

`type="number"` in html inputs may produce parser error